# Route to Controller Method tests in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, tdd

Is there a sensible way to write a low-level integration test in Laravel 5 that does the following:

When you `GET` route `/api/foo` you hit `BarController@BazMethod`.  The test makes sure that you hit `BazMethod()`, but doesn't do any more than that.  You can later modify `BazMethod` to your heart's content, but this test will always return true if that method is being called from the route.

Comment: I'd simply make that BazMethod return a whatever value and do a test to see if what /api/foo returns matches that value